# gradle handle or ignore invalid pom warning messages

Tags: apache-spark, gradle, xml-parsing, dependencies, pom.xml

When adding

the hortonworks hive warehouse connector to a gradle scala (spark) project like:

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
compile "com.hortonworks.hive:hive-warehouse-connector_2_11:1.0.0.3.1.5.9-1"
```

a lot of warnings for invalid POM are shown. Without this dependency, my project is clean without warnings. How should these be handled? Can they be fixed by gradle on the fly (or at least ignored if they are useless / not relevant):

```
[Fatal Error] hive-warehouse-connector_2.11-1.0.0.3.1.5.9-1.pom:7:3: Elementtyp "hr" muss mit dem entsprechenden Endtag "</hr>" beendet werden.
[Fatal Error] jline-2.12.1.pom:7:3: Elementtyp "hr" muss mit dem entsprechenden Endtag "</hr>" beendet werden.
[Fatal Error] hive-streaming-3.1.0.3.1.5.9-1.pom:7:3: Elementtyp "hr" muss mit dem entsprechenden Endtag "</hr>" beendet werden.
[Fatal Error] hive-service-3.1.0.3.1.5.9-1.pom:7:3: Elementtyp "hr" muss mit dem entsprechenden Endtag "</hr>" beendet werden.
[Fatal Error] hive-llap-ext-client-3.1.0.3.1.5.9-1.pom:7:3: Elementtyp "hr" muss mit dem entsprechenden Endtag "</hr>" beendet werden.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POM file located at https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/com/hortonworks/hive/hive-warehouse-connector_2.11/1.0.0.3.1.5.9-1/hive-warehouse-connector_2.11-1.0.0.3.1.5.9-1.pom looks good.
So I would double check you are indeed getting connected to that repository and not getting something like a proxy in between which does not let you access it and responds with an HTML page.

You could check what Gradle downloaded in its cache, by looking inside `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.hortonworks.hive/hive-warehouse-connector_2_11`

Comment: I deleted my caches and the problem persists

Comment: It is correct. The HWC is not the problem. It has something to do with the locationtech repository https://github.com/geoHeil/debugging-locationtech-repository

Comment: In fact https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa#maven-integration eclipse has changed the URI so moving from https://repo.locationtech.org/content/groups/releases needs to be changed to https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases is solving the issue